Azure devops fatal: could not read Username for
While trying to build in an Azure pipeline I am getting this errors:
 fatal: Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled.
 fatal: could not read Username for ****** (an azure repo)

I have added this to the yaml but the issue still persists:
  - checkout: self
     persistCredentials: true
     clean: true

The issue comes from several FetchContent_Declare in the cmake files. I've tried to redirect to url from the same +PAT but it's not working it was something like this:
git config --global url."https://PAT@dev.azure.com:".insteadOf "https://dev.azure.com"

What can I do?

PAT stands for Personal Access Token. You would use this only if you're not using a Service Principal, or if you haven't enabled Managed Identity for DevOps.
The persistCredentials setting in Azure DevOps YAML pipelines controls whether the credentials used during the pipeline run are stored and persisted for subsequent pipeline runs on the same agent. This setting is particularly relevant for self-hosted agents where you might want to reuse credentials across multiple runs. You shouldn't need it in your YAML.
To configure a pipeline to use its own identity for authentication in Azure DevOps, you can leverage Managed Identities or Service Principals depending on your requirements. Here's how you can set it up:
Using Managed Identity:
Azure DevOps supports Managed Identities for Azure resources. Managed Identities are automatically managed by Azure and are considered a more secure way to authenticate Azure resources.
Enable Managed Identity for Azure DevOps:

In the Azure portal, navigate to your Azure DevOps organization or project.
Under Project Settings, select Service connections.
Click New service connection and choose Azure Resource Manager.
Select Managed Identity as the authentication method.

Using Service Principal:
If you prefer using a Service Principal instead of Managed Identity:

Create a Service Principal:


Use Azure CLI or Azure Portal to create a Service Principal.

az ad sp create-for-rbac --name <ServicePrincipalName> --sdk-auth

Save the appId, tenant, clientSecret, and subscriptionId.


Add Service Principal to Azure DevOps:


In Azure DevOps, go to Project Settings > Service connections.
Click New service connection and choose Azure Resource Manager.
Select Service Principal (manual) as the authentication method.
Enter the Subscription ID, Subscription Name, Service Principal ID (appId), and Service Principal Key (clientSecret).


Thanks for this, and the clarification of the persistCredentials thing. We don't use Managed Identity or Service principal. And I don't even know what they are for

@silajim OK. Follow the steps under my "Enable Managed Identity for Devops" section. Ignore the "Using a Service Principal" section. Update your question with any further errors that you get.

It's not working, I don't have the necessary permissions, and I doubt they will be given to me. Are there any other options? Like setting up ssh keys or something like that.

Can you double check the exact error, and if possible the offending file and line?

Response from server: '{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'XXXXX' with object id 'xxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/read' over scope '/subscriptions

OK. That suggests that authentication is fine. That client is registered in the directory. But, it needs some permissions assigned. You'll need to get an admin to assign the Subscriptions.Read.All app permission in Entra ID. This will overcome the error you're seeing, but there may be further permissions required further on. Provide them with the client and object ID. If your pipeline needs to deploy resources to a particular subscription, or resource group, then it should be assigned the contributor role at the very least.
